# JavaScript show Images one by one

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm using this code to read array from test.php output, sort it and then show the results like a slide show.

there is something wrong at this line because only one of the images is displayed.

```
    curimg= (curimg < galleryarray.length)
    curimg + 1;
```

here is the code:

```
> <script type="text/javascript">
> var curimg=0;
> function rotateimages(){
> galleryarray.sort();
> document.getElementById("picsimg").setAttribute("src", "images/"+galleryarray[curimg]);
> curimg= (curimg < galleryarray.length);
> curimg + 1;
> }
>
> window.onload = function(){
> setInterval("rotateimages()", 2000);
> }
>
> setTimeout(function(){
>   window.location.reload(1);
> }, 20000);
>
> </script>
>
```

whats wrong with my code?

another problem that i have is that when i load the page for the first time it shows a blank page for 2000 miliseconds. //or whatever value that i've set above.

Either the delay is kicking in before the images are loaded or somehow my counting is wrong. how to fix that?

this is the output from my php code:

```
var galleryarray = new Array();
galleryarray[0] = "image1.jpg";
galleryarray[1] = "image5.jpg";
galleryarray[2] = "image2.jpg";
galleryarray[3] = "image4.jpg";
galleryarray[4] = "image8.jpg";
galleryarray[5] = "image7.jpg";
galleryarray[6] = "image0.jpg";
galleryarray[7] = "image3.jpg";
galleryarray[8] = "image6.jpg";​
```

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
curimg= (curimg < galleryarray.length);
```

you are setting the curimg to a boolean value (1 or 0). What you need to do is replace the lines as

```
if(curimg < galleryarray.length) 
    curimg = curimg + 1;
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you. now the other problem is the delay kicks in before the first image is loaded. so we see a blank page before the first image. how to fix that?

Comment: You can pre-fetch the image like it is shown [here](http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpreload.htm). The other option would be to use a javascript library like jQuery which have plug-ins which allow you to do image slieshows with less code / effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
curimg = (curimg+1) % galleryarray.length;
```

This will let you loop over galleryarray from beginning to end repeatedly.

Comment: that code works great,  there is just one problem, when the page is loaded for the first time i see a blank image, and then see the my first image. how to fix that?

Comment: `setInterval()` won't run your `rotateimages` method right away; it will wait 2 seconds before calling it for the first time. Try adding a call to `rotateimages` inside your `window.onload` handler right after your `setInterval` call.